# In Satyricon 135.4

Tags: classical-latin

"detrahentem", though a present partiple and therefore active, (it seems to me) is used passively (like the past participle "detractum".
.... Something like "She stuck the nail that had been (passively) pulled out with the wooden cup back into the grimy wall.

Guidance, please

Comment: Can you post the full sentence?

Comment: Tum clavum, qui detrahentem secutus cum camella lignea fuerat, fumoso parieti reddidit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is the sentence you're talking about:

> Tum clavum, qui detrahentem secutus cum camella lignea fuerat, fumoso parieti reddidit.
> *Then [Oenothea] replaced the nail, which had followed [her] pulling [it] down with the wooden cup, in the smoky wall.*

The key is that *quī* is nominative, while *detrahentem* is accusative, so it can't be modifying the nail itself. *Secūtus fuerat* is the main verb here, and takes an accusative object: whatever is *detrahentem* is being followed.

So my interpretation is that the nail had followed (*secūtus fuerat*) an unspoken "her", pulling down an unspoken "it", with the wooden cup (*cum camellā ligneā*).

Comment: I like this. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenBryant If this answered your question, you can click the green check mark to the left, which will mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Done. Interum tibi gratias ago.